# URL custom scheme supports ## or not in iOS Using Push Notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, url-scheme

In my application, we have deep link using a custom scheme.

If I am using like this "sampleapp://bundle?page=help" then it is working.

If I am adding ## to navigate sub-pages in the application like this "sampleapp://bundle?page=help##1" then not getting a callback is ## will supports in a custom scheme or not please help me on this.

Comment: How do you present? Using WKWebView? Then you can use its ```navigationDelegate``` to do whatever you want with links. I think out the box you can just do the links 'normally' but relatively and it should work with a simple delegate.

Comment: not WKWebview in pushnotification i am sending like this sampleapp://bundle?page=help##1 then it is not working

Comment: Maybe you need to properly escape the ##

Comment: Or add another parameter e.g. ```?page=help&sub=12```? But these are suggestions - I thought you're on WKWebView, can't really help with the pushnotes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it supports before converting string to url we need to encode the string.

```
  NSString* encodedUrl = [str stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:encodedUrl];
```